# Validate Email PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to add onto my current PHP script (below) to now validate if a user put in a correct Email.  My PHP below is to send a form to an Email address, and now I added onto it to validate the Email.  What am I doing wrong?  I am getting the $output_form = true/false; from the book Head First PHP & MySQL.  The book does not teach me how to add onto my original PHP script to send an Email.

```
<?php
$myname = $_POST['name'];
$myemail = $_POST['email'];
$mytelephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$what_service = $_POST['service'];
$mycomments = $_POST['comments'];

if (isset($POST['submit'])) {
$to = 'example@aol.com';
$subject = 'Contact Us - My Business';
$msg = "Name: $myname\n" .
"Service: $what_service\n" .
"Telephone #: $mytelephone\n" .
"Comments: $mycomments";
mail ($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $myemail);
$output_form = false;

echo '<p>Thank you for contacting us!</p>';
echo 'Your Name: ' . $myname . '<br>';
echo 'Your E-Mail: ' . $myemail . '<br>';
echo 'Your Telephone: ' . $mytelephone . '<br>';
echo 'Your Service: ' . $what_service . '<br>';
echo 'Your Comments: ' . $mycomments;

if (!filter_var($myemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
echo ' Invalid Email, please resubmit form.<br>';           
$output_form = true; } }
?>
```

Comment: you want to know how to send email using php or just validate if it is a correct email id ?

Comment: My PHP code above does send to my Email, but I just wanted to add onto it to validate if the Email was typed in correctly in my HTML form.

Comment: doesn't the validation work?

Comment: Well, the validation works, but it doesn't display my echo.  It will always submit, I just don't know if I'm even doing it right.

Comment: You don't do the validation until after you've called `mail()`. That's backwards; you should validate data *before* you try to use it. Also, you are vulnerable to [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). Finally, you really ought to format your code to make it more readable. One good, commonly-used formatting standard is [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).

Answer (score 3):

Your above code works, but the issue seems to be with where you place your validation logic. 
Try this:

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $myname = $_POST['name'];
    $myemail = $_POST['email'];
    $mytelephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $what_service = $_POST['service'];
    $mycomments = $_POST['comments'];

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { #this was $POST . Maybe a typo
    if (!filter_var($myemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    #the email is invalid. We therefore need to output the form 
    $output_form = true;               
    } else {
    #the email is valid. We do not need to output the form
   $output_form = false; 
     }

   if ($output_form == false) {
    #Since we do not need to output the form, lets proceed with sending the  mail
    $to = 'example@aol.com';
    $subject = 'Contact Us - My Business';
    $msg = "Name: $myname\n" .
    "Service: $what_service\n" .
    "Telephone #: $mytelephone\n" .
    "Comments: $mycomments";
   if (mail ($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $myemail)) { #returns true/false

    echo '<p>Thank you for contacting us!</p>';
    echo 'Your Name: ' . $myname . '<br>';
    echo 'Your E-Mail: ' . $myemail . '<br>';
    echo 'Your Telephone: ' . $mytelephone . '<br>';
    echo 'Your Service: ' . $what_service . '<br>';
    echo 'Your Comments: ' . $mycomments;
    exit;
   } else {
    #lets try and get the reason for this happening.
    print_r(error_get_last()); # this will return array of code, error and message
    exit;
   }
 } else {
echo ' Invalid Email, please resubmit form.<br>';
echo '<form><h1>TRY AGAIN</h1></form>';
}
```

}
        ?>

Comment: `if($output_form == false)` isn't this supposed to be `true` ?

Comment: @Inuka no it is right. If the email is wrong, we echo the failed result, else we proceed. Hence output form is false meaning we do not need to display the form

Comment: I see that you've done here. I assumed traditionally `output==true` will proceed sending the mail. That will be easy to read and understand by a 3rd party developer but keeping it as it is also okay when the original developer knows the logic behind it.

Comment: I just added comments as OP is a beginner

Comment: Appreciate your effort mate. This will help him understand the code. +1

Answer (score 0):

I just rearranged your code to validate email first and mail on valid email:

```
<?php
$myname = $_POST['name'];
$myemail = $_POST['email'];
$mytelephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$what_service = $_POST['service'];
$mycomments = $_POST['comments'];

if (isset($POST['submit'])) {
    $to = 'example@aol.com';
    $subject = 'Contact Us - My Business';
    $msg = "Name: $myname\n" .
    "Service: $what_service\n" .
    "Telephone #: $mytelephone\n" .
    "Comments: $mycomments";
    if (!filter_var($myemail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo ' Invalid Email, please resubmit form.<br>';           
        $output_form = true; 
    } else {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $myemail)) {
            echo '<p>Thank you for contacting us!</p>';
            echo 'Your Name: ' . $myname . '<br>';
            echo 'Your E-Mail: ' . $myemail . '<br>';
            echo 'Your Telephone: ' . $mytelephone . '<br>';
            echo 'Your Service: ' . $what_service . '<br>';
            echo 'Your Comments: ' . $mycomments;
        } else {
            eccho 'Failed';
        }           
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @Ravistm, thank you.  I will test it.  Can you tell me what $output_form = true; means?  I don't need a false anywhere?

Comment: And also what does echo 'Failed'; mean?  I haven't learned those yet?

Comment: This is correct but need little more formatting to the logic.

Comment: **echo 'Failed' => echo 'Email sending failed'**, i just made it look easier for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this code does not work.  I get a page that says Internal Server Error.

Comment: you got solution or still looking for it? if needed ill try to modify the answer

Comment: I did not get a solution.

Comment: Then you must include all your code then only we can understand and help you. 1st remove all code from your page and only run minimal required code and check it must work. 2nd if that works then add one code at a time and test and so on. You will find which code is troubling you..

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code,

```
<?php
  if (isset($POST['submit'])) {
     if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo ' Invalid Email, please resubmit form.<br>';           
       // $output_form = true; 
      } else {
        $myname = $_POST['name'];
        $myemail = $_POST['email'];
        $mytelephone = $_POST['telephone'];
        $what_service = $_POST['service'];
        $mycomments = $_POST['comments'];

        $to = 'example@aol.com';
        $subject = 'Contact Us - My Business';
        $msg = "Name: $myname\n" .
                       "Service: $what_service\n" .
                       "Telephone #: $mytelephone\n" .
                       "Comments: $mycomments";
        if(mail($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $myemail)) {
           //$output_form = false;
            echo '<p>Thank you for contacting us!</p>';
            echo 'Your Name: ' . $myname . '<br>';
            echo 'Your E-Mail: ' . $myemail . '<br>';
            echo 'Your Telephone: ' . $mytelephone . '<br>';
            echo 'Your Service: ' . $what_service . '<br>';
            echo 'Your Comments: ' . $mycomments;
        } else {
           echo 'Error in sending email';
        }
    }
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: Do I need to write $output_form = false; that are in grey above in your code?

Comment: No, they are not required. I just commented it. You can remove those lines with comments

Comment: Understand.  Also, what does the bottom part mean- else {
           echo 'Error in sending email';
        }

Comment: Sometimes if there is an error sending email, then this part of the code will be executed.

Comment: That's nice.  So why do I not need anything set to true or false like the other codes above?

Comment: They are not required here in this context & scope. But it's based on the developer who builds the logic

Comment: Last question- Why did you you put an if (mail($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $myemail))

Comment: The IF statement?

Comment: And that is to check if email sent without any problems. If not then show error message